# Each partition consists of a single row, in the case where no clustering columns are provided

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am going through the documentation of cassandra , esp Cassandra definitive guide. I come across the following statement

> ```
> Note that in the case where no clustering columns are provided, each partition consists of a single row
> ```

Isn't it each partition will contain "Group of rows" irrespective of clustering column provided( ordering) or not clustering column provided ( no ordering) - but still partition is "Group of rows" . Please add your thoughts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding answer -

When there are no clustering keys a partition can only hold a single row. This is because there is only one row for every unique primary key. A primary key is the partition key and clustering keys combined.

So if there is only a partition key there is only one row per partition. Any additional inserts with the same partition key will overwrite the previous value.

As the primary key constitutes ONLY partition key